# "HCP"."RN":Invalid identifier in my SQL SENTENCE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to obtain all the different emails and phone numbers from all the different customers created in my ORACLE 11G DATABASE.

**I was trying something like this:**

```
SELECT
    hp.party_name                              customer_name
  , hca.account_number
  , hca.cust_account_id                        
  , customer_id
    --, hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name
  , hcas.cust_acct_site_id                     customer_site_id
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address
  , hl.address1
  , hl.address2
  , hl.address3
  , hl.address4
  , hl.city
  , hl.province
  , hl.postal_code
  , hcas.status                                site_status
  , DECODE( hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N' ) usage_type
  , hca.status                                 account_status
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.cust_acct_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id /* not sure of this join */
    AND hcp.rn = 1
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number = 'number account'
;
```

---

I am getting this error message:

> It says: ORA-00904: "HCP"."RN":Invalid identifier

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does HCP return a RN column?

Comment: Hey @jarlh Hi, yeah. It should

Comment: From what I can see hcp returns the columns owner_table_id, phone_number and email_address.

Comment: @jarlh What should i change in order to make it work?

Comment: HCP isn't a table, it's an inline view, and that doesn't include an RN column. That name suggests it's perhaps supposed to be an alias for a `row_number()` (or `rank()`) expression inside that inline view. Did you maybe adapt this from another query but removed that, and added grouping instead? You would need to know the criteria to sort on to establish that numbering/ranking. Or, just remove the `AND hcp.rn = 1` clause entirely.

Comment: @AlexPoole Hey pal.. it is strange, my query should work and i have not adapted it. Still trying

Comment: @AlexPoole if i remove "AND hcp.rn = 1" i got this error message: ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_ID":Invalid identifier

Comment: Which table does CUSTOMER_ID belong to? It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, like `hca.cust_account_id` instead of just `customer_id`.